# How to set custom select classes depending on the state (selected, disabled)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set custom select classes depending on the state (selected, disabled)? How, depending on the state select (selected, disabled), set classes in a custom dropdown? Did so, but nothing happened. Look at my example, please...................................................................................

```js
    $('select').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

        $this.addClass('select-hidden');
        $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
        $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

        var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
        $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

        var $list = $('<ul />', {
            'class': 'select-options'
        }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
            $('<li />', {
                text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                // class: component.children('option').eq(i).attr('class')
            }).appendTo($list);
          
            if ($(this).children('option[disabled]')) {
              $('<li />').addClass('disabled-option');
            } else if ($(this).children('option[selected]')) {
              $('<li />').addClass('disabled-option');
            }
        }

        var $listItems = $list.children('li');

        $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
        });

        $listItems.click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
            // $this.val($(this).attr('class'));
            $list.hide();
        });

        $(document).click(function () {
            $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
            $list.hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700");

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}
.select-styled {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('img/down-arrow.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-position: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  &:active, &.active {
   // z-index: 9999;
  }
}

.select-options {
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 15px 0 rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.7);
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-indent: 15px;

    &:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
    }
    &[rel="hide"] {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.hidden {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id="">
  <option value="1" disabled>1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you explain more about your problem? Why do you need to give a class to "disabled" or "selected"? If you just want to give them a style, you can simply do it by CSS.

Comment: I need add class of active or disabled elements to list .select-options. How make with jquery?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add class to some specific options in a select element at initial rendering you can use below solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select-options option').each(function(i, e){
        //console.log(e.disabled);
        if(e.disabled) $(e).addClass('disabled');
        else if(e.selected) $(e).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.select-options {}
.select-options option {}
.select-options option.disabled {color: blue;}
.select-options option.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="" class="select-options">
  <option value="dis" disabled>Disabled</option>
  <option value="acv" selected>Selected</option>
  <option value="anv">Another One</option>
  <option value="hello">Hello</option>
</select>
```

---

Keep it in mind, you can also set/change styles for disable/selected element as follow:

CSS:

```
select option:disabled {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

If you need to add classes on change, use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select-options").get(0).addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var select = $(".select-options").get(0);
      var options = select.options;
      var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        $(selected).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  }, false);
});
```

P.S. If you need any further explanation just ask in the comment section below.

---

**EDIT**: I gave you the idea but if need your example to be modified, use this code. (Replace it with your for loop):

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++){
    if($this.children('option').eq(i).get(0).disabled){
        $('<li class="disabled-option">'+ $this.children('option').eq(i).text() +'</li>').appendTo($list);
    } else if($this.children('option').eq(i).get(0).selected){
        $('<li class="active-option">'+ $this.children('option').eq(i).text() +'</li>').appendTo($list);
    } else {
        $('<li class="">'+ $this.children('option').eq(i).text() +'</li>').appendTo($list);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer. But I need add classes (disabled, selested) to my custom select (dropdown), which code in my question )

Comment: @z_u_l Check the **EDIT** section that I've made.